# Java build Path error - (library) in (project) cannot be read or is not a valid zip file in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, samsung-mobile

tl:dr Getting error: Java Build Path Problems - Archive for required library: *library* in *project* cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file. This happens for two (~.so) I have included in the build path of an android project being developed in Eclipse. Am I doing something wrong by including the ~.so in the build path?

I am trying to install the SPen SDK in my android project and I am having problems with including some of the native library files (~.so).

I am trying to follow the tutorial specified here: [Adding S Pen library to android project](http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs). It is point 2-2 on this page.

I include the libspen22.jar to the build path which seems to be fine. But when I tried to run the application I get an error saying Java problems, with a list of 323 items stating that function *foo* must override a superclass method. I had noticed however that I hadn't included the ~.so libraries to the build path so I preceeded to add these two libraries to the build path as well. Which stopped the 323 errors but caused 2 new ones - Java Build Path Problems - Archive for required library: *library* in *project* cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file. Am I doing something wrong by including the two ~.so files in the build path for the android project being developed using Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Go to Project Properties and  set Java Compiler to 1.6 it should help.**

I don't think you need any *.so for S-Pen

Anyway, you should not include *.so in your Build Path. Any prebuilt *.so should be specified in your Android.mk like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_MODULE := foo-prebuilt
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfoo.so
   include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Please, refer to Android NDK `docs/PREBUILTS.html` But again I think it's because of Java Compiler having been set to 1.5

Comment: Thanks, it was the compiler complience level that was the issue. As soon as I set it 1.6, thanks for the help.